Finding 300th power of a given matrix
A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}
\end{bmatrix}
Find $A^{300}$. \
Clearly, The matrix has a rank of $3$. Therefore, its determinant is $0$ and nullity is $3$. So the characteristic equation is of the form $x^3(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)=0$. After that how can I proceed?

Start small by finding the square of the matrix.

Divide the matrix up in blocks of $3\times 3$ matrices.

The rank of the matrix is $4$, not $3$

It is easy to find the pattern once we divide the matrix into block matrices, and write it like $$A=\begin{bmatrix}I_3 & \frac13J_3\\0_3 & \frac13J_3\end{bmatrix}$$ where $I_3$ is the $3\times 3$ identity matrix, $J_3$ is the $3\times 3$ all one matrix and $0_3$ is the $3\times 3$ all zero matrix. These are all square matrices, so block matrix multiplication can be done.
Claim: $$A^n=\begin{bmatrix}I_3 & \frac{n}3J_3\\0_3 & \frac13J_3\end{bmatrix}$$
Proof : Induction! Clearly it holds for $n=1$. So for $n=t+1$, we get \begin{align*}A^{t+1}&=A^tA\\&=\begin{bmatrix}I_3 & \frac{t}3J_3\\0_3 & \frac13J_3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}I_3 & \frac13J_3\\0_3 & \frac13J_3\end{bmatrix}\\&=\begin{bmatrix}I_3 & \frac13J_3+\frac{t}9J_3^2\\0_3 & \frac19J_3^2\end{bmatrix}\\&=\begin{bmatrix}I_3 & \frac13J_3+\frac{t}3J_3\\0_3 & \frac{t}3J_3\end{bmatrix}\\&=\begin{bmatrix}I_3 & \frac{t+1}3J_3\\0_3 & \frac13J_3\end{bmatrix}\end{align*}
where we used the fact that $J_n^k=n^{k-1}J_n$ with $n=3$. This finishes the proof.
